# Binding Content Of ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I am making a `custom label`

```
Border CornerRadius="10"  Background="#428bca" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                White
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Border>
```

I want to bind the content of `ContentPresenter` in such a way that ,when I change the length of the content , `size`(width and height) of border will get automatically adjust so that i don't have to change it manually.

Comment: Just remove the Width and Height bindings.

Comment: No Its not Working !!

Comment: Then you may consider to add some more details about what you are trying to achieve. Are you re-styling a Label? How does your custom Label differ from the existing Label?

Comment: YES i m... basically my label has rounded corners and have some fixed background color .

Answer (score 2):

The following Label should do what you want. Note that if it is a child of e.g. a Grid, you have to set the alignment properties to some other value that the default `Stretch`, because otherwise the Label will be resized by the Panel (for example to the size of the Grid cell that it occupies).

```
<Label Content="Hello, World."
       BorderBrush="Black"
       BorderThickness="2"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
            <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="#428bca"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Label.Template>
</Label>
```

In order to reuse this ControlTemplate for all your Labels, you might put it in a default Label style:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="#428bca"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: @Ravi - if `TemplateBinding` won't work in above excellent example of @Clemens try to change it to `RelativeSource` binding

Comment: @Jasper I don't understand your comment. There is no reason why the TemplateBinding should not work. Of course it is possible to replace the TemplateBinding by a regular binding with the TemplatedParent as RelativeSource (and this is the minimum you should have mentioned), but there is no need to do that.